# php not recognising the php.ini file

Tags: php, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlsrv

i just installed PHP on my windows server 2008 and hoped to use mssql_connect() to connect with my database. When I first tried this I got the error `mssql_connect() function not found` and after a bit of searching I read that `sqlsrv driver` should be used.

I've downloaded the corresponding sqlsrv and placed it in my php/ext folder, only to find my php.ini file isn't found by PHP. I moved the .ini file to *C:\Windows* because that's the folder it's looking in.

The problem (on top of mssql_connect() not working) now is any changes made in the .ini file regarding extensions don't show in `phpinfo()`. The extension directory stays the same and no sqlsrv driver is shown.

below is the first table from phpinfo()

```html
PHP Version 5.3.29

System  Windows NT PC020025 6.1 build 7601 (Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition Service Pack 1) i586
Build Date  Aug 15 2014 19:01:45
Compiler  MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008)
Architecture  x86
Configure Command  cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--enable-debug-pack" "--disable-zts" "--disable-isapi" "--disable-nsapi" "--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql" "--without-pi3web" "--with-pdo-oci=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-11g=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient11\sdk,shared" "--with-enchant=shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared" "--with-mcrypt=static" "--disable-static-analyze"
Server API  CGI/FastCGI
Virtual Directory Support  disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path  C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File  C:\Windows\php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files  (none)
Additional .ini files parsed  (none)
PHP API  20090626
PHP Extension  20090626
Zend Extension  220090626
Zend Extension Build  API220090626,NTS,VC9
PHP Extension Build  API20090626,NTS,VC9
Debug Build  no
Thread Safety  disabled
Zend Memory Manager  enabled
Zend Multibyte Support  disabled
IPv6 Support  enabled
Registered PHP Streams  php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, zip, compress.zlib, phar
Registered Stream Socket Transports  tcp, udp
Registered Stream Filters  convert.iconv.*, mcrypt.*, mdecrypt.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk, zlib.*
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I did, I've restarted the server everytime I updated the .ini file

Comment: I've partially fixed this error. Can this post be closed?